# Python - Quotation Marks as Variables

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, arguments

Is it possible to use quotation marks as a variable?

```
a = input("Insert Here")
If a is " " ":
       Do something
```

Also, would I have to do **= or Is**?

Answer (score 1):

If you have double quotes inside a string literal then use single quotes, or escape it.

Don't use `is` unless you want to see if two references refer to the same object.  To test equality use `==`, a single `=` is an assignment:

```
a = input("Insert Here: ")
if a == '"':
   Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

1. Wrapping with single quotes: `'"'`
2. Escaping with backslash: `"\""`